# Debian does not detect when I put in my headphones

Tags: debian, audio

I have a clean install of Debian 9 and everything works fine except that I get no sound when I put in my headphones. In alsamixer, I don't even have the headphones option.

I do not have anything in my `/etc/modprobe.d` folder and therefore can not change any config files there.

Speaker sound and usb headphones work fine but not when I plug in my headphones to the 3.5mm headphonejack.

It is an Asus laptop.